# How do I Stop a service with Quartz?

Tags: c#, service, quartz-scheduler, msmq, quartz.net

I am new to MSMQ, Quartz, and services. I have a service that will send a notification email if an exception is thrown. I am trying to find a way to pause or stop the service once an email is sent so I don't receive the same exception email over and over again. I only need the email once.
So far I have tried:

1. _scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey);
2. _scheduler.UnscheduleJob(triggerKey);
3. _scheduler.Shutdown();
4. _scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);
5. serviceController.Stop();
6. serviceController.Pause();
7. _scheduler.RescheduleJob(key, exceptionTrigger);  <- over ride my old trigger with a new one that has an interval time of zero

My job and trigger code work as expected:

```
     public void CreateRegistration()
     {
        this._scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        CreateJob();
        CreateTrigger();
        RegisterWithScheduler();
     }

     public void CreateJob()
     {
       _scheduler.Start();
       this._job = JobBuilder.Create<RecieveMessageJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("ReceiveMessagesJob",      
                                  this._messageGroupName)
       .Build();
     }

     public void CreateTrigger()
     {
       _trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity(this._triggerName, this._messageGroupName)
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                .RepeatForever())
        .Build();
      }

      public void RegisterWithScheduler()
      {
            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(_job, _trigger);
      }
```

In my ReceiveMessageJob job class I look for exception errors in my execute method (Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)) and call PauseService() if need be. Here you can see all my various attempts to stop or pause my service.

```
public void PauseService()
{   
  TriggerKey triggerKey = this._trigger.Key;
  JobKey jobKey = this._job.Key;

        // Define a new Trigger 
        //ITrigger exceptionTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        //      .WithIdentity("exceptionTrigger", this._messageGroupName)
        //      .StartNow()
        //      .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        //          .WithIntervalInMinutes(0))
        //      .Build();

        // tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and put the new one in its place
        //_scheduler.RescheduleJob(key, exceptionTrigger);

        //_scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey);

        //_scheduler.UnscheduleJob(triggerKey);

        //_scheduler.Shutdown();

        //_scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);

        //ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("MessagingService");
        //serviceController.Stop();
        //serviceController.Pause();
    }
```

I can't figure out why none of my attempts have worked. Does anyone see something wrong in my code or know of a different way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand how the scheduler is tied to the service.  Do you mean a Windows NT service?  Does the scheduler run a job that starts the service?  Either way, when there's an error in the service, just have the service shut itself down.  The scheduler would have nothing to do with that.